# How to change PHP thumbnail image size?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I found a PHP script online which helps me to create a thumbnail of an uploaded image, there is only one problem: I don't know how to change the outcome size of the thumbnail. I found the tutorial at: http://www.w3schools.in/php/image-upload-and-generate-thumbnail-using-ajax-in-php/

Can anyone help me to change the outcome size of the thumbnail?

**Here is my code so far:**

```
<?php
function createDir($path){      
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        $old_mask = umask(0);
        mkdir($path, 0777, TRUE);
        umask($old_mask);
    }
}

function createThumb($path1, $path2, $file_type, $new_w, $new_h, $squareSize = ''){
    /* read the source image */
    $source_image = FALSE;

    if (preg_match("/jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG/", $file_type)) {
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
    }
    elseif (preg_match("/png|PNG/", $file_type)) {

        if (!$source_image = @imagecreatefrompng($path1)) {
            $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
        }
    }
    elseif (preg_match("/gif|GIF/", $file_type)) {
        $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($path1);
    }       
    if ($source_image == FALSE) {
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
    }

    $orig_w = imageSX($source_image);
    $orig_h = imageSY($source_image);

    if ($orig_w < $new_w && $orig_h < $new_h) {
        $desired_width = $orig_w;
        $desired_height = $orig_h;
    } else {
        $scale = min($new_w / $orig_w, $new_h / $orig_h);
        $desired_width = ceil($scale * $orig_w);
        $desired_height = ceil($scale * $orig_h);
    }

    if ($squareSize != '') {
        $desired_width = $desired_height = $squareSize;
    }

    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);
    // for PNG background white----------->
    $kek = imagecolorallocate($virtual_image, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefill($virtual_image, 0, 0, $kek);

    if ($squareSize == '') {
        /* copy source image at a resized size */
        imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $orig_w, $orig_h);
    } else {
        $wm = $orig_w / $squareSize;
        $hm = $orig_h / $squareSize;
        $h_height = $squareSize / 2;
        $w_height = $squareSize / 2;

        if ($orig_w > $orig_h) {
            $adjusted_width = $orig_w / $hm;
            $half_width = $adjusted_width / 2;
            $int_width = $half_width - $w_height;
            imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, -$int_width, 0, 0, 0, $adjusted_width, $squareSize, $orig_w, $orig_h);
        }

        elseif (($orig_w <= $orig_h)) {
            $adjusted_height = $orig_h / $wm;
            $half_height = $adjusted_height / 2;
            imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0,0, 0, 0, $squareSize, $adjusted_height, $orig_w, $orig_h);
        } else {
            imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $squareSize, $squareSize, $orig_w, $orig_h);
        }
    }

    if (@imagejpeg($virtual_image, $path2, 90)) {
        imagedestroy($virtual_image);
        imagedestroy($source_image);
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}   
?>
```

**the function gets called by the following lines of code:**

```
<?php
include('./functions.php');
/*defined settings - start*/
ini_set("memory_limit", "99M");
ini_set('post_max_size', '20M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
define('IMAGE_SMALL_DIR', './uploades/small/');
define('IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE', 50);
define('IMAGE_MEDIUM_DIR', './uploades/medium/');
define('IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE', 250);
/*defined settings - end*/

if(isset($_FILES['image_upload_file'])){
    $output['status']=FALSE;
    set_time_limit(0);
    $allowedImageType = array("image/gif",   "image/jpeg",   "image/pjpeg",   "image/png",   "image/x-png"  );

    if ($_FILES['image_upload_file']["error"] > 0) {
        $output['error']= "Error in File";
    }
    elseif (!in_array($_FILES['image_upload_file']["type"], $allowedImageType)) {
        $output['error']= "You can only upload JPG, PNG and GIF file";
    }
    elseif (round($_FILES['image_upload_file']["size"] / 1024) > 4096) {
        $output['error']= "You can upload file size up to 4 MB";
    } else {
        /*create directory with 777 permission if not exist - start*/
        createDir(IMAGE_SMALL_DIR);
        createDir(IMAGE_MEDIUM_DIR);
        /*create directory with 777 permission if not exist - end*/
        $path[0] = $_FILES['image_upload_file']['tmp_name'];
        $file = pathinfo($_FILES['image_upload_file']['name']);
        $fileType = $file["extension"];
        $desiredExt='jpg';
        $fileNameNew = rand(333, 999) . time() . ".$desiredExt";
        $path[1] = IMAGE_MEDIUM_DIR . $fileNameNew;
        $path[2] = IMAGE_SMALL_DIR . $fileNameNew;

        if (createThumb($path[0], $path[1], $fileType, IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE, IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE,IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE)) {

            if (createThumb($path[1], $path[2],"$desiredExt", IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE, IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE,IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE)) {
                $output['status']=TRUE;
                $output['image_medium']= $path[1];
                $output['image_small']= $path[2];
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}
?>
```

Comment: we don't either, since the sizes are set by the arguments TO the function. in other words, it depends on how you CALL the function, not how the function operates.

Comment: @MarcB I made an edit to my post, did you mean this? I'm sort of new to PHP and I'm slowely starting to learn the basics. Thanks in advantage!

Comment: @MarcB I already found it out! It can be found in the define part, thanks anyway!

Comment: Change the values of the defined variables at the top. IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE as well as IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE is used when creating thumbs as you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that you found the answer to your own problem. I wanted to add some additional insight.

**The Right Way**

Ideally you should be passing a param to the method as you can reset it if desired:

```
$imageSize = 100; // size

createThumb($path[0], $path[1], $fileType, $imageSize, $imageSize, $imageSize);
```

**The Wrong Way**

The script above is using constants. They are outlined with the define method. IE.

```
define('IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE', 50);
define('IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE', 250);
```

Change the number to your desired size. Ie

```
define('IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE', 150);
```

In this particular use case, the constants are still being passed into the function which defeats the need for a constant.